# How can I hide some properties for this inherited label?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, inheritance

I have the following code. How can I hide the `AutoEllipsis`, `Image`, `ImageAlign`, `ImageIndex`, `ImageKey`, `ImageList` and `TabIndex` properties?

Also, how do I set the default size to 50x50px?

```
public class GradientBox : Label
{
    [DefaultValue(false), Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public override bool AutoSize { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(false), Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public override string Text { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(false), Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public override ContentAlignment TextAlign { get; set; }

    // NullRef Exception if use { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(false), Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public override Font Font
    {
        get { return base.Font; }
        set { base.Font = value; }
    }

    public override BorderStyle BorderStyle
    {
        get { return BorderStyle.FixedSingle; }
        set { base.BorderStyle = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new LinearGradientBrush(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, this.Height), this.ForeColor, this.BackColor), ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be in violation of Liskov's Substitution Principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Answer (score 3):

When you inherit from something, your new class needs to be able to behave as if it were the base type (one aspect of polymorphism).  That means it can't provide *less* functionality than the base.  So there's no way to remove those properties, because otherwise it wouldn't be a `Label`.

What you might want to consider is "Composition" instead.

```
public class GradientBox : Control
{
    private Label myLabel;
    public GradientBox()
    {
        myLabel = new Label;
        // Set your default values
    }


    public Font Font
    {
        get { return myLabel.Font; }
        set { myLabel.Font = value; }
    }
    // repeat to expose just the properties you want.
 }
```